# Does or can eclipse's C++ autocompletion consider namespace members?

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete, code-assist

I've noticed that when I type `somenamespace::<tab>` inside Eclipse [Kepler] in a C++ project it does not show only the namespace members as the first suggestions, instead showing a very long list of possibilities. Is there a way to configure Eclipse to first suggest only the explicit members of that namespace?

Comment: I've also experienced this behavior. Sometimes it helps to scroll up from the lists backend (especially for enum values & alike).

Comment: Oh good, it puts the most useful stuff at the very bottom. :-P